# Bash script works in Python, but not in the CLI. bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: python, batch-file

I am new to Stack Overflow and bash/sh commands. I ran into the following issue when trying to execute a shell command in 2 different ways:

1. Executing the script from the Bash CLI
2. Executing the script from a Python IDE

The script is as follows:

```
For /R C:\\Users\\userid\\Desktop\\my-test\\src\\api-explorer\\ %G IN (*.json) do widdershins "%G" -o "%G".md
```

The intent of the script is to recursively convert a number of Swagger.json files to Markdown files using a conversion tool called Widdershins.

The script runs fine when executing it from Python like this:

```py
def convertSwaggerToMarkdown():
    cmd = 'For /R C:\\Users\\userid\\Desktop\\my-test\\src\\api-explorer\\ %G IN (*.json) do widdershins "%G" -o "%G".md
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

Where it fails, is when I try to execute the script in Bash directly. I've tried the recommendations from other users that encountered a similar error, which suggest appending either the `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` to the beginning of the command, but when doing this the command does not execute and also does not provide any error.

I also tried suggestions to add " " around the (*json), since this appears to be where the issue resides. Since the script executes in Python when shell=True, I'm certain there is a syntax error which I am overlooking, and also a better needed understanding of how the logic between bash and sh scripts work.

In Bash, this is what it looks like:

[Syntax Error Unexpected Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E0ox.jpg)

What am I missing here?

Comment: `cmd.exe` and bash are two different languages. You can't expect to run the same code in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script is not bash. My guess is it is PowerShell, a scripting language used in Windows that fills a similar role as Bash. The correct Bash syntax would be

```
for g in *.json; do
  widdershins $g -o $g.md
done
```

If you want the command to be recursive, best option is to use the `find` command, e.g.

```
find . -name \*.json -type f -exec widdershins \{\} -o \{\}.md \;
```

Or as an alternative, launch PowerShell to run your script instead of Bash. PowerShell is actually cross platform these days.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as long as I'm cd'd into the folder directly, but how would I implement that same command in a recursive fashion using bash?

Comment: OK so that was what /R did :) See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have worked recursively. I saw a few of these errors: 'Error: Unrecognised input format' but in checking my markdowns it did not have any affect on the conversion or display of the data. Perhaps an issue on the tool's end. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your original command should work happily if executed directly from the `cmd` prompt - although the double-`\` are unnecessary.

If you are executing that command as a line in a `*.bat` file, then each `%G` needs to have the `%` doubled `%%G` as `G` here is a metavariable. Again, the double-`\` are unnecessary.